# ¿Cómo descargar un archivo con php?

Tags: php, mysql

Deseaba saber como descargar un archivo `php` , produje un ciclo `while` para recorrer y otorgar la ruta correspondiente, cree una carpeta llamado "subidas " para subir la dirección , por ej : ../subidas/  para subir mis archivos , probé el siguiente código :

```html
<a href="#" download="<?php echo $row["RUTA"] ?>">
```

Me Hace la descarga de un archivo pdf pero es inutilizable , desconozco si esta es la manera correcta , apreciara la ayuda! Gracias!

[image: Este es el campo donde guardo la ruta para luego descargar en mysql]

(EDITADO)

```html
if (isset($_FILES["file"]) && !empty($_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
    $archivoExist = $_FILES["file"]["name"]; //Variable que almacena el archivo ,su nombre
    $directorio = "../DIR/"; //Directorio de carpeta subidas donde se subiran los archivos
    $archivo = $directorio . basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]); //Archivo principal donde se sube
    $tipoArhivo = strtolower(pathinfo($archivo, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if (!file_exists($archivo)) { //Si no existe el archivo entonces se p
        if ($tipoArhivo == "pdf" || $tipoArhivo == "jpg" || $tipoArhivo == "png") {
            if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $archivo)) {
            
            //Validaciones e insercion
            }
            }
            }
            }
```

Aquí se puede ver como obtengo el archivo enviado.

Comment: ¿Y ese PDF es *utilizable* en su origen? Si en el origen el archivo está corrompido, es lógico que lo estará allí donde lo descargues.

Comment: @A.Cedano Gracias por responder! , Es utilizable en su origen , no me explico porque no funciona.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y agrega el código completo que usas para gestionar la obtención del archivo.

Comment: @A.Cedano Editado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La url del archivo a descarga debe de ir en el atributo href, en el atributo download debe ir el nombre que quieres darle al archivo descargado, también debes de cambiar las comillas dobles por comillas simples en `$row["RUTA"]`, deberías obtener un resultado similar a este:

`<a href="<?php echo $row['RUTA'] ?>" download="NOMBRE_DEL_ARCHIVO">`

Comment: Hola amigo! Gracias por la ayuda, resulta que me indica que no se pudo descargar ya que no hay ningun archivo , produje esto : <a href="<?php echo $row['RUTA'] ?>" download="Nombre_archivo">

Comment: Probe con eliminar el download y dejar solo el href y me indica esto :  The requested URL /DIR/ejemplo.pdf was not found on this server. habia hecho antes para descargar archivos y me funcionaba con solo dejar el href  pero esta vez no

Comment: Prueba usar <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['RUTA'])?>" download="Nombre_archivo">